# Changing the default imagefield formatter for a node field

Tags: entities, 6, media

I am trying to change the default formatter for an imagefield node form field so that it will default to the thumbnail image and not the icon. I have already tried a form alter and that isn't doing a damn bit of good. I have already flushed all the cache. So I was wondering if anyone else knew how to do this.

I am running Drupal 6 by the way. The field in question is using imagecache presets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the GUI tools allowed me to change the default. So I ended up writing a little JavaScript to select the option I wanted on form load.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the admin for the content type in question and look at the display fields, eg, `admin/content/node-type/THISCONTENTTYPE/display` and change up the field you want.  You can select any imagecache preset you have defined on your system along with a number of other options.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no options for neither positioning nor a default option to be selected. I dug around for this in both the interface and the code for a very long time.

Comment: on what type of page are you trying to change this then? meaning, are you trying to change it when the node is being displayed or edited or?

Comment: The formatters are appearing in a modal window after clicking on a button in the wysiwyg and it is done this way through wysiwyg_fields module. Actually more specifically the appear in the module window after an image is uploaded in it, which comes after that button is pressed in the wysiwyg. I ended up fixing this with a jQuery call that waits until after each ajax call is completed (called ajaxComplete()) and then tries to find the field and select one automatically.

Comment: By the way, I voted your answer up for your help.